# Linq list for month+year for the whole year

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for linq query to fill a list with month + year for example (January 2012)

starting form current month

```
   var currentdate = System.DateTime.Now
```

If Dec 2011 is the current month 
then list should be like this

December 2011 
January 2012
......
November 2012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm editing to turn my sample code into a method that I might almost use in production because it's more testable and culture-aware:

```
public IEnumerable GetMonths(DateTime currentDate, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
           let now = currentDate.AddMonths(i)
           select new
           {
               MonthLabel = now.ToString("MMMM", provider),
               Month = now.Month,
               Year = now.Year
           };
}
```

This outputs (on a French computer):

[image: LINQPad Output]

Answer (score 8):

```
var months = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, 12).
    Select(n => DateTime.Today.AddMonths(n)).
    Select(d = new { Year = d.Year, Month = d.Month });
```