# How to Show Items as Month Names if we bind numbers as items in Dropdown list in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime

I Have Dropdown list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedMonth,Model.getMonths(),  new { @id = "ddlMonth"})
```

Now, I want to Show Month Names in Dropdown list from Database "Week_Calender" Table, for that  I have written linq query like

```
public SelectList getMonths()
{
    var monthslist = (from week in res.WEEK_CALENDER where week.WEEK_START_DT.Month <= DateTime.Now.Month select new { week.WEEK_START_DT.Month }).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text =m.Month.ToString(), Value = m.Month.ToString() });

    return new SelectList(monthslist, "Value", "Text", month_num); ;
}
```

But here Dropdown will show only month numbers but i want to show Month Names based on Month numbers. How it is Possible, Please Help me.

Comment: Could use the `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames` property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ya, But I want to show the Month Names upto Current Month Only, is it Possible?

Comment: Yes, Get the current Month numerical value using `DateTime.Now` and use that to filter the Month names returned from `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames` - note that the names are in a 0-based array

Answer (score 2):

u can try like this as well

```
public SelectList getMonths()
{
    var monthslist = (from week in res.WEEK_CALENDER where week.WEEK_START_DT.Month <= DateTime.Now.Month select new { week.WEEK_START_DT.Month }).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text =(convert.ToDateTime(2000,m,1)).ToString("MMMM"), Value = (convert.ToDateTime(2000,m,1)).ToString("MMMM") });

    return new SelectList(monthslist, "Value", "Text", month_num); ;
}
```

Try this

Comment: You should do this in a list view op wants that type

Comment: u need to check for the month... that will come under the number... right... now convert that number into datetime... but to get that month u need to fitst take default date and year... so take that and then convert it inot tostring using `MMMM`

Answer (score 0):

**Do**

`Text = m.ToString("MMMM")`

*Instead of*

`Text = m.Month.ToString()`

Another Alternative

```
var data = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
                  let now = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i)
                  select new
                  {
                       MonthLabel = now.ToString("MMMM"),
                       Month = now.Month
                  };
```

for reference follow [Get Month Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560134/linq-list-for-monthyear-for-the-whole-year/8560177#8560177)

Comment: No It is not getting...!! I think we should do something in "Text=""" like Providing DateTime Provider.

Comment: where actually you want the name of the month? in Text ?

Comment: Yes, That will show Month Names in Dropdown list with respect to Values as Month Numbers, But what you have given answer again is not correct, and It is not getting. can you give more suggestions

Comment: I have edited the answer just do the same with Text instead of Value, it will solve your problem

Comment: It is Showing as all "MMMM" in Dropdown   instead of Month Names.

Comment: check what is this returning?
`string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");`

Answer (score 0):

Lets try with

month for shortname e.g. Jun

```
Text = m.ToString("MMM")
```

month for fullname e.g. June

```
Text = m.ToString("MMMM")
```

instead

```
Text = m.Month.ToString()
```

For more month format just refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public SelectList getMonths()
{
    var monthslist = (from week in res.WEEK_CALENDER where week.WEEK_START_DT.Month <= DateTime.Now.Month select new { week.WEEK_START_DT.Month }).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text =m.Month.Value.ToString("MMMM"), Value = m.Month.Value.ToString("MMMM") });

    return new SelectList(monthslist, "Value", "Text", month_num); ;
}
```

Comment: the issue is that instead of showing June its showing 6

Comment: which column_name should i provide??

Comment: Getting error like "'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"